# Primefaces Datatable submits wrong data by Celledit

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm using Primefaces datatable with PF8.

Data is coming from ListDatamodel. I want to use Cell editing and implemented it exactly like shown in Primefaces showcase. After 3 or 4 inputs of new values, in the approriate bean the value gets updated, but with the old value. After a refresh of the page, the behaviour is normal again.

Here is the xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable  style= "transform: scale(1); transform-origin: 0 0;" id="costingOverviewData" value="#{costingOverviewBean.model}" var="item" 
        editable="true" editMode="cell"  selectionMode="single" disabledSelection="true"
        rowStyleClass="#{(item.konto % 1000) eq 999 ? 'total':null}"
        rowKey="#{item.ID}"
        
        >

        
        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{costingOverviewBean.onCellEdit}" process="@this" />
        
        <p:column rendered = "#{costingOverviewBean.showVorkalk ne false}" style="min-width: 20px;width:20px; max-width: 20px;">
            <h:outputText value="#{item.konto}" />  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column style="min-width: 200px;width:200px; max-width: 200px;" >  
            <h:outputText value="#{item.beschreibung}" />  
        </p:column>  
        <p:column rendered = "#{costingOverviewBean.showVorkalk eq true}" width="75" headerText="#{res['COV_VorkalkQuantity']}" style="text-align:right">
             
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <p:outputPanel   style="#{item.menge_Vorkalk ne null ? 'border-style:solid;border-color:grey;border-width:0.5pt':'border-style:none'}">
                    <p:outputLabel   value="#{item.menge_Vorkalk}">
                    <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"></f:convertNumber>
                    </p:outputLabel>
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputNumber rendered="#{item.menge_Vorkalk ne null ? 'true':'false'}" id="menge_Vorkalk_Input" value="#{item.menge_Vorkalk}" style="width:96%">
             </p:inputNumber>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
```

...

And here the bean:

```
public DataModel <KontenrahmenIstkosten> getModel() throws IOException {
    if(model == null){
            load_Strukturplan();
        }
    if (model == null){
         model = new ListDataModel<KontenrahmenIstkosten>(list);
            converter = new NumberConverter();
    }
        return this.model;
    }
...
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) throws IOException {
         System.out.println(event.getNewValue());
        System.out.println(event.getRowKey());
        
        
            
            init();
            //PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("form:pnlOfferEdit");
    }
    }
```

In extreme cases, I got also wrong data in fields which I never touched, and the whole table is messed up.

I'm struggling for 3 days now. Any help is appreciated!!

Edit: during value editing, getmodel() is called several times **before** calling of onCellEdit().

Is this normal behaviour? From my feeling, I face here a timing issue: Sometimes it is luckily working, sometimes not.

Comment: Have you followed the showcase example exactly? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml

Comment: Yes, only difference is the the use of ListDataModel instead of list, which I need for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it without the process="@this"?
This only submits the values from the component.

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{costingOverviewBean.onCellEdit}"/>
```

Or you can try adding the id instead of @this

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{costingOverviewBean.onCellEdit}" process="costingOverviewData"/>
```

Comment: I tried it with all variations: without process attribute, with process="costingOverviewData", with process="@this". Always the same result: after a certain number of inputs the new value was not shown in onCellEdit, whiel the client side logtool from Primeface show the right value to submit.

Comment: Ok, I would try to remove every code that is not necessary. 
I don't know your application, but I would try to remove the rendered in the cellEdit event first.


<p:inputNumber rendered="#{item.menge_Vorkalk ne null ? 'true':'false'}" id="menge_Vorkalk_Input" value="#{item.menge_Vorkalk}" style="width:96%">

By the way, you just need to write rendered="#{item.menge_Vorkalk ne null}"

Comment: Just now I made a blank Primeface page without any templates, and here I removed the "rendered="-attributes. And here it seems to work. But what is the reason for this behaviour? I really need the "rendered"-attribute in this application.

Comment: Edit: I removed the rendered-attributes in the original page, and the error appears again! So, reason for the error seems to be the integration in the template.

Comment: It could be any component on the page, you just have to remove bit by bit to check when it works/fails. 
Or you should post the whole code for the page.

Comment: You where right! I have found a p:defaultcommand in my template file, which obviously prevent the proper submit. Removing of this defaultcommand solved the problem. Thanks for your help